# restore root ownership of files from a mounted file system

Tags: ubuntu, boot, mount, chown, ownership

I have a `/dev/nvme0n1p3` ext4 partition where I have installed ubuntu 18.04

My personal files are at `/home/sas/data`

I created a different `/dev/nvme0n1p2` ext4 partition, where I installed ubuntu 22.04

The idea was to mount the disk from the ubuntu 18.04 partition and add a link to the `/home/sas/data` folder, so I can work from both partitions, until I migrate everything.

I mounted the disk at `/media/ubuntu1804/` adding this line to my `/etc/fstab` file

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
UUID=83ff0b98-de90-... /media/ubuntu1804 ext4    defaults        0       2
```

the problem was that all the files had owner and group as 1001.

I tried manually mounting the partition with:

```
$ sudo umount ubuntu1804

$ sudo mount -t ext4 -o gid=1000,uid=1000 /dev/nvme0n1p3 /media/ubuntu1804
mount: /media/ubuntu1804: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/nvme0n1p3, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

by mistake (alas!) I tried with the following:

```bash
$ sudo chown -R root ./ubuntu1804/
```

without realizing that I would be changing the ownsership of the files neded by the 18.04 os!!!! (I should have tried with some folder inside `/home/sas/data`)

now the 18.04 partition cannot boot, with this message:

```
[FAILED] Failed to start Create Static Device Nodes in /dev
...


[  OK  ] Started GNOME Display manager. Dispatcher Service... d.tem changes.pp link was shut down
```

Any idea how can I boot into the original 18.04 OS and try to fix things, restoring the original ownership of the OS files?

Comment: Reinstall the Ubuntu 18.04, either from scratch or from your most recent backup